# HTML Input field with bootstrap class: width changes when I add certain attributes

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have two inputs on the same row and I want both input fields to fill the parent container (a "col-sm-10" and "col-sm-2", respectively) width-wise. If I just leave it this way:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <label for="inputA">Cliente:</label>                
    <input class="form-control" id="inputA" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label for="inputB">NIF:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="inputB" />
</div>
```

[Then I have no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beVpc.png)

However, If I add certain attributes to the input (such as type="text" OR runat="server"(I need this to process the input programmatically)), [the width of the first input changes and it no longer fills the parent container:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUAH.png)

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <label for="inputA">Cliente:</label>                
    <input class="form-control" id="inputA" type="text" runat="server"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label for="inputB">NIF:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="inputB" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

The most amazing thing is that if I change type="text" to type="number" it works. See the image, since I can't post more than 2 links: **i.stack.imgur.com/aN3us.png**

I tried using the  control with CssClass="form-control" and the same behavior happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dpjoe0Lt/8/) of your code and it runs perfectly.
I think that you might have another css style that is overwriting your style.

You should check for `input[type='text']`. I would suggest you that you open the browser developer tools select your input type and in the right side you have all your styles that are applying to that element. 
You should check for width and it also tells you file where this style is coming from and the line.

Also you can add full width by yourself

```
.col-sm-10 #inputA{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When creating an asp.net web forms project, there's a Site.css file in which several input types are fixed with a max-width of 280px. I don't know why do they do that, since the default project also has bootstrap theming. I just commented the conflicting part and it is working nice now. Thanks

Also, if you don't mind answering this: which is preferable? Using the default html input or the <asp:TextBox > control? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not really good at asp so i don't wanna give you any incorrect  answer. Maybe you can check here in stack for that question or you can create one if you can't find any information about that. Vote me up :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any css style in the form of input[type="text"] with custom width.